# Stopping a background service when the app is closed.(or minized)

Tags: android, android-service

my application contains several activities. (Above 10).
When the app is started inside the splash activity (some might argue apps should not have splash, but that's not the point here) I am starting a service.

However, since many activities are present, and the app is a user driven app, the user might be in any of the activities when he/she decides to leave the app or even minimize it.

My question is, do I need to include a check in every single onPause / onStop of every single activity to check if my service is running, and if it is doing so, stop it ? Or , there is a something that needs to be done at a single place ?

To check if my service is running, I am using the following.

```
    private boolean isMyServiceRunning()
{
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
    {
        if (MyService.class.getName()
                .equals(service.service.getClassName()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a service in the first place? The point behind a service is to do work when there is no activity in the foreground.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know. And I won't use this technique, just want to know if there is a way technically to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a service by extending Service, then this service will be closed when you close app.

&

If you created a service by extending IntentService, then this service will be closed automatically when all the intents are executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop a service via the **stopService()** method. Just one call to the **stopService()** method stops the service.

A service can terminate itself by calling the **stopSelf()** method. Do This in the service class when it finishes its work.

Comment: @methalhead1247, you totally missed the question. time to switch to rap music.

Comment: @tony9099  You should switch to Metal you'll never get  a question/error again :P

Answer (score 0):

You can extend standart activity once with overloaded onPause/onResume etc methotds and use it. Throug this you can control all Activities state through one peace of code.